# Avoid constructor calls when deserializing with jackson

Tags: java, json, constructor, jackson, deserialization

i have a class that has a `UUID` attribute that is being generated in the constructor, so it means it's generated every time a new object is created.

I am using Jackson to deserialize json strings into objects with `ObjectMapper`. The issue is that when i deserialize, it deserializes the json string into a new object, and calls the constructor of the class, which results in generating a new `UUID`. So basically it takes the Json string that already has a `UUID`, and when it deserializes it changes it to a new one.

Any ideas how to solve this using Jackson?

Comment: You cannot avoid Jackson using constructor - It's better to change the constructor.

Comment: I'm surprised the UUID is not being overwritten with the one in the JSON.  Is the UUID final?

Comment: When i used Gson i saw that the same issue does not occur,  that's why i believed it can be avoided in some way with Jackson too.

Comment: @JoseMartinez it's not final, i was surprised too.

Comment: Is the id field of type UUID or does it get converted to a String?

Comment: it is converted to a String like this -> uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

Comment: Please add your complete bean class that you’re trying to de-serialize.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce.  In my answer below I show that ObjectMapper will do the right thing and overwrite the ID.  Can you post your code?

Comment: I'm sorry, i am not at liberty to share the code. The bean is just a regular bean with the constructor mentioned in the question. One thing does seem suspicious though. The setter for the UUID attribute checks if the attribute is null and does not set it if it is not null. Could this be the issue? Maybe it does not rewrite because of this setter?

Comment: You can't share a single bean class even renamed (in case of NDA) and with renamed properties? Are you serious?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I could've renamed it, but it's solved now anyways. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that i had a setter which checked if `UUID` was null, and if it was not, it did not set it to the new one. So when the object was created it automatically got a `UUID`, and Jackson couldn't set it with the setter since it was not null. When i removed the `if` from the setter, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a second private constructor and annotate this constructor with `@JsonCreator`. This will make Jackson use this constructor for de-serialization. You can add additional arguments to the constructor and annotate the arguments with `@JsonProperty` - I think - to make Jackson set the respective values correctly.

Comment: Nice, just one question, is a constructor with this annotation used when i create new objects myself?

Comment: If you make the constructor private it can’t be used from outside.

Comment: Sorry, i missed that part.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce the problem.  Below is my code.  It works as expected.

```
public static class MyPojo {
    private String id;

    public MyPojo() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    var om = new ObjectMapper();
    var myPojo = om.readValue(" {\"id\":\"6d1eab11-d64f-4152-9955-3d5c54828cd9\"}", MyPojo.class);
    assertThat(myPojo.id).isEqualTo("6d1eab11-d64f-4152-9955-3d5c54828cd9");
    System.out.println("id = " + myPojo.id);
}
```

Comment: The setter was checking if the id is null and if it was not, it did not set it. That was the issue. Thanks for your assistance, i'm upvoting your answer since it helped a lot.